# Head/Tail command to grab multiple sets of lines

Tags: pipe, tail, head

I have to grab the first two lines, the lines 43 and 44, and the last 2 lines from a file in one conduct of commands.
Is there away to print those while only using head, tail and pipe commands AND without special operators like && or ;?
All I could think of is this

```
(cat cool | head -n 2) | (tail -n +43 | head -n 2) | (tail -n  2)
```

but it has cat...
AND another option is

```
(head -n 2 < cool) | (tail -n +43 < cool | head -n 2) | (tail -n 2 < cool)
```

but for some reason it only shows the last line

Comment: "_Is there away to print those while only using head, tail and pipe commands_" - yes there is. Given the artificial constraints this sounds like homework, so please [edit] your question to show your own attempts

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the (homework?) question. In my opinion this is less complicated than that, you are just supposed to provide THREE separate commands: one for the first two lines, one for the lines 43 and 44 and finally the last 2 lines. There are solutions, though, to do the three operations in one single command.

Comment: I forgot to add, but our teacher said to try and only use one command that's why I did it in one haha. The thing is I can only find a way to combine three commands using && or ; which are prohibited for the question... That's why I'm really confused. I'll edit my post to make it more precise!

Answer (score 1):

`cat cool | head` is an example of [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) (Useless use of cat). Let's examine your second bit of code:

```
(head -n 2 < cool) | (tail -n +43 < cool | head -n 2) | (tail -n 2 < cool)
```

What should strike you is that `| command < cool` redirects stdin twice. You have to choose either the result of the previous piped commands, or the file `cool`. Both is not an option.

Now back to your problem. The solution with **one single file read** is to:

- Read the first 42 lines, display only the first two and discard the 40 lines that follow. This translates to `head -n 42 | head -n 2`.
- Display the next two lines (lines 43 and 44). This translates to `head -n 2`.
- Display the last two lines. This translates to `tail -n 2`.

Now put all these together:

```
( head -n 42 | head -n 2; head -n 2; tail -n 2 ) < cool
```

Alternative, similar reasoning:

```
( head -n 2; head -n 42 | tail -n 2; tail -n 2 ) < cool
```

Comment: @Chris Hmmm, `head` and `tail` should operate on lines, not blocks. What system are you using? Does adding `stdbuf -iL` before each `head` and `tail` change anything?

Comment: it depends on the implementation of `head` if it takes care to read only the lines it needs to read (i.e. seek back when reading from a file, or abysmally slowly reading a byte at a time when reading from a pipe). GNU and Busybox seemed to seek the file, but I wouldn't be surprised if some implementation didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since the constraint is to use only `head` and `tail`, I don't believe it's possible to answer the requirement with a single command:

```
# First two lines of the file "cool"
head -n2 cool

# Lines 43 and 44
head -n44 cool | tail -n2

# Last 2 lines
tail -n2 cool
```

You can crash these together as a single line of three commands, but it's not "*one command*" as stated in your question:

```
head -n2 cool; head -n44 cool | tail -n2; tail -n2 cool
```

You may want to refresh your understanding of the `head` and `tail` commands by using the installed documentation: see `man head` and `man tail`.