# Extract parts of a string using head and tail only

Tags: bash, pipe, tail, head

Hello I would like to know if there is a way where I can only use head, tail, and pipes (and redirection eventually) to extract and output the start, middle characters, and end of a string

Example:
Given this string: `SHOWpijfirefjTHISezpijSTRING`, the command should output 'SHOWTHISSTRING'

I tried something like
`(head -c 4 mdp > /dev/tty) | (tail -c +13 mdp | head -c 4 > /dev/tty) | (tail -c 6 mdp > /dev/tty) 2>&1`

but it doesn't always return the same result and can give out of order results

Comment: The arbitrary restriction to just `head` and `tail` make this sound like homework. Read `man head tail `.

Comment: Piping processes together makes them all run simultaneously, and is pointless, as none of the subshells uses any stdin or stdout anyway. That is why you get data out of order. Writing /dev/tty from 3 different places is not going to help. The `13` is wrong: byte counts are from zero, but start positions start from 1. But generally, the `head` and `tail` ore OK -- the redirections, subshells and pipes are the issue.

Comment: sounds similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/759186/170373

Answer (score 2):

You can with the `head` implementations that support that non-standard `-c` option and are smart enough not to read more than needed from their input when asking to output a fixed number of bytes:

```
string='SHOWpijfirefjTHISezpijSTRING'
printf %s "$string" | {
  head -c 4
  head -c 9 > /dev/null
  head -c 4
  tail -c 6
}
```

See how it works with GNU `head` or the `head` builtin of `ksh93`, but not the `head` of busybox. If you run `strace -fe read busybox sh ./that-script`, you'll see:

```
[pid  7739] read(0, "SHOWpijfirefjTHISezpijSTRING", 4096) = 28
```

Where the first `head` consumes all the input by reading a full block and outputs 4 bytes of it, leaving nothing to read for the  next `head` and `tail` commands.

While with GNU or ksh93 `head`:

```
[pid 10293] read(0, "SHOW", 4)          = 4
```

Also beware `head` and `tail` with `-c` work with bytes, not characters¹ so can only be used to report fix numbers of characters with text encoded with one byte per character.

Most modern shells will have builtin operators to slice strings based on character position.

For instance, in zsh or yash:

```
slice=${string[1,4]}${string[14,17]}${string[-4,-1]}
```

In zsh, can be shortened to:

```
slice=$string[1,4]$string[14,17]$string[-6,-1]
```

And you can cut off bits in place:

```
$ string[5,13]= string[9,-7]=
$ print -r -- $string
SHOWTHISSTRING
```

Or with recent versions of `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh` or `mksh`:

```
slice=${string:0:4}${string:13:4}${string: -6}
```

POSIXly:

```
tmp=${string#?????????????}
slice=${string%"${string#????}"}${tmp%"${tmp#????}"}${string#"${string%????}"}
```

---

<sup>¹ despite what *c* may suggest. That `-c` option was added to some `head` implementations to align with the `-c` of `tail`, and the `-c` was added to `tail` long before the notion that a character could be made of more than one byte.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `head` and `tail` support the `-c` option, that your string is nothing but simple ASCII with no multi-byte characters, and that your shell supports the `<<<` here string construct (bash and zsh do), you can do:

```
$ string=SHOWpijfirefjTHISezpijSTRING
$ printf '%s%s%s\n' "$(head -c 4 <<<"$string")" \
                    "$(head -c 17 <<<"$string" | tail -c 4)" \
                    "$( tail -c 5 <<<"$string")"
SHOWTHISRING
```

Or, if you don't want `printf`:

```
$ string=SHOWpijfirefjTHISezpijSTRING
$ head -c 4 <<<"$string"; \
  head -c 17 <<<"$string" | tail -c 4; \
  tail -c 5 <<<"$string"; 
SHOWTHISRING
```